# Extracting pdf images in a correct order iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to extract images from a PDF File, but I really need to have it at the correct order to get the correct image.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename = "D:\\910723575_marca_coletiva.pdf";

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filename);

        var imagemList = ExtraiImagens(pdfReader);

        // converter byte[] para um bmp
        List<Bitmap> bmpSrcList = new List<Bitmap>();
        IList<byte[]> imagensProcessadas = new List<byte[]>();

        foreach (var imagem in imagemList)
        {

            System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
            try
            {
                Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(imagem);
                ConsoleWriteImage(img);
                imagensProcessadas.Add(imagem);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                continue;
            }

        }

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ConsoleWriteImage(Image img)
    {
        int sMax = 39;
        decimal percent = Math.Min(decimal.Divide(sMax, img.Width), decimal.Divide(sMax, img.Height));
        Size resSize = new Size((int)(img.Width * percent), (int)(img.Height * percent));
        Func<System.Drawing.Color, int> ToConsoleColor = c =>
        {
            int index = (c.R > 128 | c.G > 128 | c.B > 128) ? 8 : 0;
            index |= (c.R > 64) ? 4 : 0;
            index |= (c.G > 64) ? 2 : 0;
            index |= (c.B > 64) ? 1 : 0;
            return index;
        };
        Bitmap bmpMin = new Bitmap(img, resSize.Width, resSize.Height);
        Bitmap bmpMax = new Bitmap(img, resSize.Width * 2, resSize.Height * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < resSize.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < resSize.Width; j++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)ToConsoleColor(bmpMin.GetPixel(j, i));
                Console.Write("██");
            }

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.Write("    ");

            for (int j = 0; j < resSize.Width; j++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)ToConsoleColor(bmpMax.GetPixel(j * 2, i * 2));
                Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)ToConsoleColor(bmpMax.GetPixel(j * 2, i * 2 + 1));
                Console.Write("▀");

                Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)ToConsoleColor(bmpMax.GetPixel(j * 2 + 1, i * 2));
                Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)ToConsoleColor(bmpMax.GetPixel(j * 2 + 1, i * 2 + 1));
                Console.Write("▀");
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static IList<byte[]> ExtraiImagens(PdfReader pdfReader) 
    {
        var data = new byte[] { };

        IList<byte[]> imagensList = new List<byte[]>();

        for (int numPag = 1; numPag <= 3; numPag++)
        //for (int numPag = 1; numPag <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; numPag++)
        {
            var pg = pdfReader.GetPageN(numPag);
            var res = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pg.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES)) as PdfDictionary;
            var xobj = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(res.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT)) as PdfDictionary;
            if (xobj == null) continue;

            var keys = xobj.Keys;
            if (keys == null) continue;

            PdfObject obj = null;
            PdfDictionary tg = null;

            for (int key = 0; key < keys.Count; key++)
            {
                obj = xobj.Get(keys.ElementAt(key));

                if (!obj.IsIndirect()) continue;

                tg = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj) as PdfDictionary;

                obj = xobj.Get(keys.ElementAt(key));
                if (!obj.IsIndirect()) continue;
                tg = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj) as PdfDictionary;

                var type = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)) as PdfName;
                if (!PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(type)) continue;

                int XrefIndex = (obj as PRIndirectReference).Number;
                var pdfStream = pdfReader.GetPdfObject(XrefIndex) as PRStream;

                data = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw(pdfStream);

                imagensList.Add(PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw(pdfStream));
            }
        }

        return imagensList;
    }
}
```

The method ConsoleWriteImage is only to print the image at the console and I used it to study the behavior of the order that iTextSharp was retrieving it for me , based on my code.

Any help ?

Comment: What is the *correct order*?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the OP has not explained what *the correct order* is - this is not self-explanatory because there might be certain aspects of a PDF which are not obvious for a program, merely for a human reader viewing the rendered PDF.

At least, though, it is likely that the OP wants to get his images on a page-by-page basis. This obviously is not what his current code provides: His code scans the whole base of objects inside the PDF for image objects, so he will get image objects, but the order may be completely random; in particular he may even get images contained in the PDF but not used on any of its pages...

To retrieve images on a page-by-page order (and only images actually used), one should use the parser framework, e.g.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
MyImageRenderListener listener = new MyImageRenderListener();
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
  parser.ProcessContent(i, listener);
} 
// Process images in the List listener.MyImages
// with names in listener.ImageNames
```

*(Excerpt from the [ExtractImages.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/book/blob/master/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter15/ExtractImages.cs) iTextSharp example)*

where `MyImageRenderListener` is defined to collect images:

```
public class MyImageRenderListener : IRenderListener {
    /** the byte array of the extracted images */
    private List<byte[]> _myImages;
    public List<byte[]> MyImages {
      get { return _myImages; }
    }
    /** the file names of the extracted images */
    private List<string> _imageNames;
    public List<string> ImageNames { 
      get { return _imageNames; }
    } 

    public MyImageRenderListener() {
      _myImages = new List<byte[]>();
      _imageNames = new List<string>();
    }

    [...]

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
      try {
        PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
        if (image == null || image.GetImageBytesType() == PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.JBIG2) 
          return;

        _imageNames.Add(string.Format("Image{0}.{1}", renderInfo.GetRef().Number, image.GetFileType() ) );
        _myImages.Add(image.GetImageAsBytes());
      }
      catch
      {
      }
    }

    [...]      
}
```

*(Excerpt from [MyImageRenderListener.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/book/blob/master/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter15/MyImageRenderListener.cs) iTextSharp example)*

The `ImageRenderInfo renderInfo` furthermore also contains information on location and orientation of the image on the page in question which might help to deduce the *correct order* the OP is after.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my late reply, I'll try to use this solution to my problem and as soon as possible I'll give a feedback for this ! Tks in advance for your help !

Comment: only to check if I understood ... There isn't a way to order those images at the pdf parse . The only parameter that I have is the MyImageRenderListener, where I have the details from the image right? And a question, I really don't know how the iTextSharp inserts the image in the file. But is it any kind of container where the size is fixed but the image could vary inside of this container ? If yes , do you think that could be a parameter to look after the image that I need ?

Comment: *There isn't a way to order those images at the pdf parse* - there is. But it may not be the order you want. E.g. they might be ordered in the sequence they are drawn. Or somehow ordered by coordinates. Neither of which needs to be the reading order.

Comment: *I really don't know how the iTextSharp inserts the image in the file.* - it essentially copies the image from the resources of the page, transforming the format if necessary.

Comment: *But is it any kind of container where the size is fixed but the image could vary inside of this container ?* - the image from the resources is subject to an affine transformation when drawn on some page, it can be moved, rotated, mirrored, skewed, or any combination thereof.

Comment: This affine transformation can be retrieved from the `ImageRenderInfo` object as transformation matrix.