# Image extract from pdf using itextsharp in c#

Tags: c#, pdf

Hello i am using

```
     public void ExtractImagesFromPDF(string sourcePdf, string outputPath)
    {
        // NOTE: This will only get the first image it finds per page.
        PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(sourcePdf);
        RandomAccessFileOrArray raf = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(sourcePdf);

        try
        {
            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= pdf.NumberOfPages; pageNumber++)
            {
                Response.Write("Page " + pageNumber.ToString());
                PdfDictionary pg = pdf.GetPageN(pageNumber);

                // recursively search pages, forms and groups for images.
                PdfObject obj = FindImageInPDFDictionary(pg);

                if (obj != null)
                {

                    int XrefIndex = Convert.ToInt32(((PRIndirectReference)obj).Number.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    PdfObject pdfObj = pdf.GetPdfObject(XrefIndex);
                    PdfStream pdfStrem = (PdfStream)pdfObj;
                    bytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)pdfStrem);
                    if ((bytes != null))
                    {




                        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
                        {
                            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            memStream.Position = 0;
                            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream);
                            // must save the file while stream is open.
                            if (!Directory.Exists(outputPath))
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);

                            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(outputPath, String.Format(@"{0}.jpg", pageNumber));
                            System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters parms = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
                            parms.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, 0);
                            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo jpegEncoder = GetEncoder(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            img.Save(path, jpegEncoder, parms);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            pdf.Close();
            raf.Close();
        }


    }
```

code but does not extract my pdf file , parameter is not valid error and i am using third party dll use for extract image so where get all images from pdf but i want to use itextsharp dll , please check and help me.

Comment: Which Parameter is not valid?

Comment: parameter is not valid. at system.drawing.image.fromstream

Comment: Your code uses iTextSharp only for lowlevel operations and tries to transform the stream contents to images itself and does so in a way which works only for a fraction of the possible PDF image formats. How about using the iTextSharp high level `parser` API for the task?

Comment: @mkl  which api available for extract image from pdf. ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39458888/1729265) may help you.